# SimpleSAMLphp - Use own session in custom module

Tags: php, session, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I'm trying to create my own authentication module on SimpleSAMLphp using this class :
https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/v1.18.8/modules/exampleauth/lib/Auth/Source/External.php

The goal is to create an IdP initiated login so the users only have to click on a link to go to the SP.

I followed all the instructions but i can't use my own session in this class in the getUser function.

After debugging i figured my session gets overwritten by SimpleSAMLphp session.

If i break the code on the getUser function ( i called a function on a null object by accident ), my session isn't erased, which i think is weird. Maybe it resets my session on failure ?

I tried

```
$session = \SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest();
$session->cleanup();
```

and

```
$session = \SimpleSAML\Session::getSession();
$session->cleanup();
```

How can i use my own session in this situation ?

Thank you

I'm using the same SimpleSAMLphp installation for both IdP and SP ( 2 different workflows ), is this problematic ? Should i install it twice if i need both SP & IdP ?

I'm using simpleSAMLphp v1.18.8 with php5.6.

Thank you.